# jQuery cssHook - override standard element.css() behaviour

Tags: jquery, css, plugins

There is a thing in `jQuery` that allows to create custom css properties:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

For an example I want to add some feature to the `jQuery.transit`: https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit

I want to make CSS `left` and `top` properties identical to `x` and `y` in jQuery.transit (`x` and `y` are becoming `transform: translate(x, y)`)

So, according to `jQuery.cssHooks` manual and internal `jQuery.transit` API I add `left` and `top`:

```
registerCssHook('left', true);

/* some code */

setter {
  /* some code */
  left: function(x) {
    this.set('translate', x, null);
  },
  /* some code */
}

/* some code */

getter {
  /* some code */
  left: function() {
    return this._translateX || 0;
  },
  /* some code */
}

/* some code */

function registerCssHook(prop, isPixels) {
  // For certain properties, the 'px' should not be implied.
  if (!isPixels) { $.cssNumber[prop] = true; }

  $.transit.propertyMap[prop] = support.transform;

  $.cssHooks[prop] = {
    get: function(elem) {
      var t = $(elem).css('transit:transform');
      return t.get(prop);
    },

    set: function(elem, value) {
      var t = $(elem).css('transit:transform');
      t.setFromString(prop, value);

      $(elem).css({ 'transit:transform': t });
    }
  };
}
```

And everything is almost fine. Now when i type

```
$('.class').css('left', '40px');
```

All `.class` elements get:

- `transform: translate(x, y)` style
- aaand.. still `left: x` style